# Set application icon for FileChooser in javaFX

Tags: java, javafx-2, fxml

After I start a FileChooser window in my javaFX application in windows the application icon in the taskbar shows a java icon and not the icon of the main window. Is there a possibility to select an application icon for a FileChooser instance?

Thanks for your answeres!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to do so, but apparently only when you have a **visible** parent stage.

Provided that `stage` in the following example is visible, you can do this:

```
stage.getIcons().add(new Image("http://i.imgur.com/1M3UaZy.png"));
FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
File result = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(stage);
```

This opens the file chooser as a child of the given stage, which has the given icon.

I stepped through the JavaFX source code with a debugger (Oracle Java 8u72 on Windows x64), and there is not single point in the Java code where the icon could be set. The parent window handle is passed into a native method, where it then the icon probably gets resolved somewhere in the Win32 windowing code.

Comment: Thanks! This solution works. Sadly to know that the FileChooser cannot have it's own Image...

Comment: @TobiasL. Recently, I started Scene Builder (which also presents you a standalone FileChooser) from a terminal and the FileChooser got the icon of the terminal... So it's definitely that.

Answer (score 1):

This is an ugly hack based on [RAnders00 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35274098/3870761). It calls `show` before the `showSaveDialog` call, plus it calls `stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED)` so we don't get an unwanted window.

In addition, it only worked using resource icons, and not the url example icon.

```
    // For me it only worked with resource icons, nor url example icon
    stage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("icon.png")));
    
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

    // App icon show hack
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED); // Remove unwanted window (no buttons no window)
    stage.show();

    File result = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(stage);

    // Close app icon       
    stage.hide();
```

Only tested on windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the above solution is, that it won't work out of the box when you are using FXML-controllers. That troubled me for a while, but finally I found a solution for that, which I'd like to share with you.

First you need to assign you topmost pane wihtin your fxml-file an id, for instance:

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="563.0" prefWidth="442.0" scaleShape="false" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:id="primaryStageAnchorPane" fx:controller="application.MyController">
```

Now you can use this id in your controller to create the link:

```
@FXML
private AnchorPane primaryStageAnchorPane;
```

That whas the hard part. All you need to do now is to get the window-attributes of the linked pane (which are the ones from the primary stage of your application-file):

```
Stage stage = (Stage) primaryStageAnchorPane.getScene().getWindow();
FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
File tempFolder = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage);
```

This will overtake the main application's icon for your filechooser-window. As a side-effect your file-chooser won't appear as a seperate item in the task-bar anymore.

Worked for me, hopes it helps somebody out there :)